# How do I get this effect in Unity3D?

Tags: unity

Here is a mockup of a main menu screen I'm trying to put together in Unity.

I'm clueless as to how I should go about creating the blue glow on the left of my menu options.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

[image: Mockup]

Comment: It looks like just a blue gradient. That shouldn't be hard. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Transparent texture over the entire screen?

Comment: @ashes999:  It is indeed nothing more than a blue gradient.  I'm just not clear on how (if it is even possible) to do this natively in Unity.

Comment: @ktodisco:  could you elaborate?

Comment: It looks like you are using a GUI library which is probably creating a Camera specifically for the gui buttons. Use that camera and render a GUITexture or better yet a planar Mesh and use a gradient with alpha falloff in a material. You can probably also make the gradient texture 1px tall and set it to Wrap instead of Clamp in the texture properties window.

Comment: @blz You take a blue gradient, render it as a GUITexture over the entire screen, and set the alpha to some value like 0.5, so the scene behind the menu is still visible.  Also, to save on space you can take Rubber Mallet's advice by making the gradient only 1px tall.  For starters though, you can just make it the size of the screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will want to create your background (gradient) in another program such as Photoshop or GIMP, and then import it. Following that, simply draw it to the screen in the position you want it. Stretching gradients works well because of bilinear filtering: so you don't need to worry about making it massive (e.g. 512x512 should work fine).

*There is no reason to use shaders/effects here*.

Comment: I couldn't edit this in because it would be changing the answer: but you might want to mention creating a simple white gradient and then altering the color of it with a shader. This will allow him to re-use it in other places.

Comment: +1 for simplicity.  Using `GUI.DrawTexture()` should be all you need: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.DrawTexture.html

Answer (score -3):

u have apply another texture when mouse over on button

Comment: he was talking about the light background gradient on the left, not the buttons